how to logging logs in table using mssql server with workloadidentity along with private endpoints?
When am using mssqlserver for errors logging in log table along with workidentity.
version:Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServerCore :"1.1.1"
platform:windows,linux
using below code for trying to connect
WorkloadIdentityConfig workloadIdentityConfig = GetWorkloadIdentityConfiguration(services);
var conn = new SqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
SqlAuthenticationProvider.SetProvider(
SqlAuthenticationMethod.ActiveDirectoryWorkloadIdentity,
new CustomAzureSQLAuthProvider(workloadIdentityConfig));
logger = (Serilog.ILogger)loggerConfiguration
//.MinimumLevel.Information()
.WriteTo.MSSqlServer(conn.ConnectionString
, Configuration.GetSection("LoggingConfigurations:TableName").Value
, (Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel)Enum.Parse(typeof(Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel), Configuration["LoggingConfigurations:LogLevel"])).MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Error)
.CreateLogger();
services.AddSingleton(logger);

Expected behavior
I am expecting logs are logging into table.but no logs logged in to the table when am using workloadidentity.
